# Matrix Representation Question (with Derivative)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The solution was confusing to me so I did it this way:

$E=[e^x,xe^x,x^2e^x]$

$[D(f)]_E=A[f]_E$

$A$ is a $3x3$ matrix where **a**$_j=[D($**e**$_j)]_E$ for $j = 1, 2, 3$

But I am stuck on evaluating them. The way I had it in my head was for example:

**a**$_1=[D($**e**$_1)]_E = [e^x]_E = (1,0,0)^T$

I don't think it makes sense going from $[D($**e**$_1)]_E = [e^x]_E$

I don't see how I can take derivative of **e**$_1$ which is a standard basis vector of $(1,0,0)^T$. This entire attempt is probably incorrect, but it made the most sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write $e_1=(1,0,0)$, you should be referring to a basis, in this case the basis is $\{ e^x, xe^x, x^2e^x\}$

Think of $(1,0,0)$ as representation of $1\cdot e^x + 0\cdot xe^x + 0 \cdot x^2e^x$ which explains why did they compute $D(1\cdot e^x + 0\cdot xe^x + 0 \cdot x^2e^x)=D(e^x)$ in their working.

Comment: so for example the standard basis vector $e_1$ for $R^2$ is $(1,0)$, what basis do we refer to here?

Comment: $\{ (1,0), (0,1)\}$, Hence $(1,0)=1\cdot (1,0)+0(0,1)$.

Comment: you have enlightened me. what do you think about my attempt? it looks like it works?

Comment: your method should agree with the solution provided right?

Comment: the subspace is spanned by $e^x,xe^x,x^2e^x$ but it doesn't say that the vectors are a basis for $S$ so im wondering if $e$ is still a standard basis vector

Comment: the subspace is spanned by $x^x, xe^x, x^2e^x$, to check that they form a basis, check that they are linearly independent.